# How to do different operations with user in same thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am working for the first time on jmeter, I had a thread group of 2 users and I had given all the parameters in HTTP requests and executed the test plan and it worked fine, but in "View result tree" it is shown that user1 logged in imported a file and logged out and then user2 logged in done the same and logged out.What should I do to make user1 to do some work until the user2 logged in and they should be logged out one by one. I had tried to add a screen shot but for adding screen shot its asking for 10 reputation.

Comment: Check synchronization timer.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter kicks off threads representing virtual users during defined ramp-up time. Once started each thread begins to execute samplers upside down. When there are no samplers to execute and no more loops to cycle thread is being shut down.

It is not guaranteed that you will have as many users doing the same stuff as you have defined in the thread group.

In order to achieve better control there is [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) which can pause the threads under its scope until desired amount is available and fires them at exactly the same moment of time.

For more information on the Synchronizing timer like where to place and how to use see [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) guide.